# Suddenly started getting 403 mod security action, WAF- azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

We have application (OHDSI Atlas- http) deployed on Azure Cloud (ISAS). We have set up of WAF in prevention mode.  The application is working since last 8 months.
Suddenly since last 2 weeks we are getting 403 for PUT and POST requests. Mostly looks like SQL injection rules and some Protocol related.

We had also raised request with MS support, and we had disabled some of the rules. It was working properly, but again started getting different rule hits. 
The code is as it is since last 8 months.

Note-
Recently, When we had added one more application to same application gateway with https. Is this can affect the other application?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be related to the backend application. It could be that in past 2 weeks you are seeing activity which seems anomalous to WAF. It is recommended to turn on WAF diagnostics logs and look at details of the request which caused WAF rules to trigger.